# Find tight bound on $T(n) = T(n/2) + \log^2(n)$

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I am trying to solve the following recurrence:

$$T(n) = T(n/2) + \left(\log_2(n)\right)^2$$

with $T(1)=1$

I want to find the $\Theta$ bound for the expression.

I came up with an expression to turn this into a summation but it was pointed out by El Pasta to be incorrect.

Comment: Your expression is strange, $\sum_{0}^{\log(n)}$ is very weird, because $\log(n)$ in generally is not a integer number

Comment: Sorry, thank you for pointing that out. Then I don't have a clue how to solve this.

Comment: Relax, Do you have an initial condition as $T(1)=$ a number?

Comment: Yes $T(1) = 1$. Sorry for missing out on this information. First time asking a question here :)

Comment: Try using [the master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Case_1_example)

Comment: I tried doing it using master theorem. But I couldn't understand how to apply it in this context. Also I wanted to solve this using unrolling to better understand the underlying relation.

Answer (score 2):

If
$n = 2^m$,
then
this standard substitution gives
$T(n) = T(n/2) + \left(\log_2(n)\right)^2
$
which becomes
$T(2^m) 
= T(2^{m-1}) + \left(\log_2(2^m)\right)^2
= T(2^{m-1}) + m^2
$.

Letting
$s(m) = T(2^m)$,
this is
$s(m) = s(m-1)+m^2
$
with
$s(0) = T(1) = 1$
or
$s(m)-s(m-1) = m^2$.

Summing
$\displaystyle s(n)-s(0)
=\sum_{m=1}^n(s(m)-s(m-1)) 
= \sum_{m=1}^nm^2
=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$
so
$\displaystyle T(2^n)
=s(n)
=s(0)+\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
=1+\dfrac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{6}
$.

Setting
$m = 2^n$,
so $n = \log_2(m)$,
this becomes
$\displaystyle T(m)
=1+\dfrac{2\log_2^3(m)+3\log_2^2(m)+\log_2(m)}{6}
=\dfrac1{3}\log_2^3(m)+O\left(\log_2^2(m)\right)
$.

In general,
if
$\displaystyle T(n) = T(n/2) + \left(\log_2(n)\right)^k
$,
this will yield
$\displaystyle T(m)
=\dfrac1{k+1}\log_2^{k+1}(m)+O(\log_2^{k}(m))
$.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. How do we go from $T(m)=\frac{1}{k+1}log^{K+1}(m) + O(log^k(m))$ to finding the $\Theta$ bound for the recurrence?

Comment: This gives $T(m) = \Theta(\log_2^{k+1}(m))$.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant to ask what would $T(n)$ be in terms of the $\Theta$ bound?